# Python 2.7.8: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

when i write simple:

```
sqli = ("SELECT SUM(obtained) FROM stobt  WHERE stid = %d " ) %(row2)
```

gives no error and prints,

but when i write:

```
sqli = ("SELECT SUM(obtained) FROM stobt  WHERE stid = %d and subject='%s'" ) %(row2,sub)
```

gives me error which made me sick:

Error:

`TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple`

for more here is my db:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python "TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845285/python-typeerror-d-format-a-number-is-required-not-tuple)

Comment: yh i gone thru but i dont have any stray commas. or do i ve?

Comment: Your example works for me well (Python 2.7.9). Check if `row2` is really a number or you changed the value to a tuple.

Comment: rows2 is printing stid very well. But when i place in query creates error

Comment: is my query correct?

Comment: Anyway it is recommended to use parametrized queries. Version of your code is on slide 2 of [SQL injection](http://www.slideshare.net/openpbs/sql-injection-defense-in-python) presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is bound to creation of query string and has nothing to do with real database (yet).

If `row2` is an integer and `sub` is a string, it works for me:

```
>>> row2 = 12
>>> "SELECT SUM(obtained) FROM stobt  WHERE stid = %d " % (row2)
'SELECT SUM(obtained) FROM stobt  WHERE stid = 12 '
>>> sub = "subject"
>>> "SELECT SUM(obtained) FROM stobt  WHERE stid = %d and subject='%s'" % (row2, sub)
"SELECT SUM(obtained) FROM stobt  WHERE stid = 12 and subject='subject'"
>>> ("SELECT SUM(obtained) FROM stobt  WHERE stid = %d and subject='%s'") % (row2, sub)
"SELECT SUM(obtained) FROM stobt  WHERE stid = 12 and subject='subject'"
>>> type(row2)
int
```

Make sure, you did not change the value of `row2`.